# django - remember data between bound and unbound forms

Tags: python, django, forms, post

I'm defining a new `Form`, using `__init()__` to modify the queryset for a  `ModelMultipleChoiceField` and also adding a variable that i will use for the query:

```
class ProductPickerForChangeForm(forms.Form):
products = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    total_amount = kwargs.pop('total_amount', None)
    super(ProductPickerForChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if user and total_amount:
        self.fields['products'].queryset = # stuff
        self.total_amount = total_amount
```

now, in `views.py` I'm creating a new unbound form for the `GET` request (and the parameters are coming from the user):

```
form = ProductPickerForChangeForm(user=request.user, total_amount=amount)
```

but, how to recover the data previously used for creating the unbound form when I'm creating the bound form from the `POST` request (the queryset could have changed in the meantime) - and without the risk of users messing with the posted data, too?

Comment: You can use the session.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are actually trying to do here?

Comment: I'm creating a form for product returning. So basically an user picks products he wants to change (= an amount of money) and with another forms he picks an amount of products to receive.